# table,trigger,.. in deleted connection still exist in new conection SQL DEVELOPER .how delete all table, ...and they doesn't exit in new conection??

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

ORACLE_SQL DEVELOPER : table,trigger,.. in deleted connection  still exist in new conection
[image: ORACLE_SQL DEVELOPER : table,trigger,.. in connection deleted still exist in new conection]

Comment: Deleting connections in your client (sql developer) has ZERO impact on the contents of your database

Comment: so how to delete content of database

Comment: Right click on the the TRIGGER, drop it

Comment: anyway to drop all table, trigger , ... in only one step

Comment: That's a different question

Comment: @huyvo - Potentially, you want to drop the user that owns the schema in which all the objects have been created.  Assuming, of course, that you know how to create a new user to own the objects you're going to want to create next.